# Xamarin Forms - Wordpress API Response Codes

Tags: c#, json, wordpress, xamarin.forms, wordpress-rest-api

I want to query my wordpress website using the API.

I simply want to check if a username and password provided in the url is valid by returning a response code.

Here's the API i'm using:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users?consumer_key=xxx&consumer_secret=xxx&username=xxx&password=xxx
```

Is it possible to simply check if the username and password is valid by passing the API request through the url?

If it's successful, return response code 200, if unsuccessful return another response code etc.

Comment: Is that your authentication method or some built-in WordPress feature?  You should never pass credentials into the URI as parameters because such things can appear as plain text in server logs (even if you did use HTTPS).  Best to place in the request header/body.

Comment: Thanks @MickyD yes it's just a basic authentication for now and will tighten up the security around it. Just need to figure out how to get a response code from wordpress using the credentials.

Comment: What do the docs say about this?  Why don't you do a simple test to determine what the response code is for valid credentials vs. invalid credentials?